# Include the CSS bullet along the <LI> tag

Tags: html, css

I did a fiddle to showcase the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/1xum5Lce/4/

**The HTML:**

```
<ul class="font anim">
  <li class="bckA">Hello</li>
  <li class="bckB">World</li>
</ul>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.bckA {
  background-color: #FFFFAA;
}

.bckB {
  background-color: #AAFFFF;
}

.anim li {
  transition: all 200ms;
  transform-origin: left;
}

.anim li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000000;
}

.font {
  font-size: 36px;
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

The background color and the shadow when hovering are only covering the label, and the transform-origin is between the bullet and the label.

I need the bullet to be included in all this.

Note that I don't want to add the numbering manually since the `<LI>` tags change their order dynamically. Also, physically setting the bullet inside doesn't handle the margin correctly during line-wraps.

What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: Check updated fiddle if this is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/1xum5Lce/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS [counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) instead of `list-style-type: decimal`. This way, you also have the possibility to style the numbers different than the rest of the listitem.

```css
.bckA { background-color: #FFFFAA; }
.bckB { background-color: #AAFFFF; }

.anim li {
  counter-increment: number;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 40px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  transform-origin: left;
}

.anim li::before {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  content: counter(number) ". ";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  text-align: right;
  width: 35px;
}

.anim li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  z-index: 2;
}

.font {
  font-size: 36px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="font anim">
  <li class="bckA">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy</li>
  <li class="bckB">World</li>
</ul>
```

Edit: To align text after a line-break, we'll give the counter a fixed width and let it stick to the left with `position: absolute` (don't forget to add `position: relative` and `z-index` to the listitem).

`height` isn't necessary for `::before` but it shows how it actually works.

Comment: There's a small issue with the margin if I set the bullet inside. It won't handle line wraps the same way as with the bullet outside.

Comment: You mean after a line-break the text should be aligned?

Comment: Yes, after a line-break the text should not align on the bullet.

Comment: I changed it - I'll add an explanation in a minute

Comment: I implemented your solution in my module, and it works like a charm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Use [list-style-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position) with a value of `inside` if you want to include the bullet inside the `li` element:

```css
.bckA {
  background-color: #FFFFAA;
}

.bckB {
  background-color: #AAFFFF;
}

.anim li {
  transition: all 200ms;
  transform-origin: left;
}

.anim li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.font {
  font-size: 36px;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  list-style-position: inside;  
}
```

```html
<ul class="font anim">
  <li class="bckA">Hello</li>
  <li class="bckB">World</li>
</ul>
```

If you are having issues with multiple lines with `list-style-position: inside`, you can use extra/pseudo elements as the markers instead of using default list markers. To keep track of the list item, you can use [css counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).

Comment: Didn't know about `list-style-position: inside`, thanks!

Comment: There's a small issue with the margin if I set the bullet inside. It won't handle line wraps the same way as with the bullet outside.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. Yes, setting `list-style-position` to `inside` makes the marker to be included in first block inside the `li` element. If that's not what you want, I would suggest using an extra element for the marker( you can use `counter` to track the decimal value ).

Comment: I think I see your solution. That may do it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

it will work with li::before

change you your css like this

check this :
https://jsfiddle.net/bfahmi/1xum5Lce/7/

```
.bckA {
   background-color: #FFFFAA;
}

.bckB {
   background-color: #AAFFFF;
}

.anim {
    counter-reset: section;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.anim li{
  transition: all 200ms;
  transform-origin: left;
}
.anim li::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counter(section) ". ";
}

.anim li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple approach use ordered list not unordered list and use css to style according.

```html
<ol>
      <li>List 1</li>
      <li>List 2</li>
      <li>List 3</li>
     </ol>
```

Comment: You misread the question, it is not how to get numbers instead of bullets